# Excel- How to return a Nested ISBLANK IF statement that has different variants for each cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, say `A1 = Rodgers` `B1 = Mahomes` `C1 =`  `D1=`  `E1= Jackson`

How can I do a combined nested if statement for each variant, if they are blank they stay blank.

So, my variants are If `A1` contains a value then `Packers = Rodgers`, if `B1` contains a value then `Chiefs = Mahomes`, If `E1` Contains a value then `Ravens = Jackson`.

The final output would not have `C1` and `D1` as they return blank cells. I would then drag that down to 500 cells below that.

I can do a single one `= If(ISBLANK(A1)," ","Packers:"&A1))` but I can't do a combined one, I have tried `If(ISBLANK(A1)," ","Packers:"&A1, If(ISBLANK(B1)," ","Chiefs:"&B1)))` but this is not working

Comment: Have a list and use vlookup() or match(). If the value is in the list it is true etc.

Comment: I am not sure how I can list or match it to as they would all different values. For example, A2 could be Adams and then B2 could be empty. So my output, I would want the Packers text to return Adams but then it would be empty because there is no B2

Comment: No, Packers = Rodgers is the output for the first row. I mean vertically 500 cells below Rodgers there are some cells that are blank some have values. For example, A2 has Adams but then A3 is blank. So in my output, I would want no "Packers =" as there is a blank cell in A3 hence why I am using =ISBlank. I need to combine them together with non blank and blank cells.

Comment: You can add a screenshot of sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Put the team names in a `CHOOSE` statement:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=0,"",CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(COLUMN(A1),"Packers","Chiefs","Cowboys","Bears","Ravens"),":",A1))
```

Then you should be able to fill another four columns to the right and all the way down.